# Grails `respond` returns null

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

I want to send validation errors back to a different page (add), so I have this for my `save` action:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
def save(AddDomainCommand command) {

    if (command.validate() && session.isLoggedIn && session.publisher) {
        // do some stuff
        return redirect(controller: 'Widget', action: 'generate')
    }

    log.info("Validation failed for $command")
    respond view: "add", model: [domain: command]
}
```

It errors with `javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'save' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'`

If I print the response from `respond`, I get `null`! So that explains why it's going to `save`, because that's the convention for the action's name.

I need it to go back to the view it came from (`add.gsp`), yet grails `respond` is null and thus defaulting to `save.gsp`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`respond` uses a different syntax and is used when you want to be able to support multiple client types based on mime type, e.g. JSON and/or XML for a REST client and HTML/GSP for a regular browser client. If you just want to use `add.gsp` to render HTML, use `render`:

```
render view: 'add', model: [domain: command]
```

Comment: This works elsewhere though. I use `respond view: "add", model: [a: b] and it works correctly.

Comment: Same thing happens if I use `render` instead of `respond`